# Android - Arranging imageViews in a grid in RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, imageview, margin

I'm trying to figure out some method of arranging ImageViews in a grid in a RelativeLayout with margins. I don't want to use a GridView or GridLayout because I would like to change the posoition of the ImageViews later.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Try what? Putting it in a GridView?

Comment: this can be managed with making `GridView` with a custom `Adapter`. even changing the positions later is perfectly feasible with such a method. i'd give it a shot.

Comment: Can I set the x and y exactly?